# What's the idiomatic way of performing conversions from python gflags to yaml and back?

Tags: python, yaml, abseil

I'm using [absl-py](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py)'s python gflags for my project.

They're a convenient way of specifying configurations, but I frequently like to run the same configuration, and saving command line invocations is not preferable because they are hard to read and maintain.

I'd like to instead be able to maintain YAML text files that specify flag values. For instance, a program that might be invoked as

```
python myapp.py --some_int_arg 3 --noboolean_value
```

could also be invoked as

```
python myapp.py --from_config config.yaml
```

where the contents of `config.yaml` are

```
some_int_arg: 3
boolean_value: false
```

and analogously it'd be nice to be able to construct the file above given the first invocation.

What is the most idiomatic way of

1. accepting a configuration file path on the command line and having that  override all `absl.flags.FLAGS` values?
2. converting an `absl.flags.FLAGS` instance to a text representation (preferably YAML) that can then be reinvoked using (1)?

**Edit**. There seems to be an easy way to accept a configuration file, using `--flagfile`, which should just contain each flag's values on a new line. However, my question (2) still stands, how would I be able to recover such a file? Currently the only solution seems to be to crawl `flags.FLAGS` and stringify each flag value manually.

Comment: I don't know about absl-py, but I have done this with YAML and a wrapper around the standard `argparse` library. The code is in [`ruamel.appconfig`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.appconfig/) and used in many of the utilities that I published on PyPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLAGS.flags_into_string()` should return a string that can be put in a flagfile. Or `FLAGS.append_flags_into_file('path/to/flagfile.txt')` will append the flags to that file.

Does this work for you?